# Android phones, updates and supported SDK versions

Tags: android, version

I am having trouble finding a list of Android phones and their current supported Android versions so I could figure out the broadest target audience for my app.

Comment: find here: http://www.andro-phones.com/2010-android-phones.php and http://www.honeytechblog.com/android-phones/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the official [stat](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) from Google.